# What does a Bash command do to the file typed in afterwards?

Tags: bash, shell

I just learned that the `bash` command opens up a new Bash shell inside of whatever shell you're using, and uses the profile of `.bashrc` for its commands.

When I was installing Laravel earlier this week, I used a `bash init.sh` command. Now I'm wondering, what exactly did that `bash init.sh` command do?  Why did I need to open a new shell to... execute or open whatever was in `init.sh`?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting `man bash`<sup>*</sup>:

> **ARGUMENTS**
>
> If arguments remain after option processing, and neither the `-c` nor the `-s` option has been supplied, the first argument is assumed to be the name of a file containing shell commands. If `bash` is invoked in this fashion, `$0` is set to the name of the file, and the positional parameters are set to the remaining arguments. *Bash* reads and executes commands from this file, then exits. *Bash*'s exit status is the exit status of the last command executed in the script. If no commands are executed, the exit status is 0. An attempt is first made to open the file in the current directory, and, if no file is found, then the shell searches the directories in `PATH` for the script.

In other words: `bash <file>` executes `<file>` as a Bash script. You will *not* get a new interactive shell.

Note that this is not the only way to specify which shell (or indeed any command) should be used to execute a script: It's common to use a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) for that, so that the script can be ‘executed’ by itself.

---

<sup>* The one I had at hand, of Bash v4.3.42.</sup>